# C# Как вызвать приватный метод внутри метода поля?

Tags: c#, ооп

В данном пример метод `CreateShape` публичный, но я хочу, чтобы он был недоступен из вне, но был доступен только для реализаций `IShapeProviderState`. Это возможно реализовать?

**Пояснению к коду** `ShapeProvider` возвращает объект типа `Shape`, делается это с помощью задания поля `ShapeProvider - IShapeProvider Provider`. У `Provider` есть метод `GetShape`. Т.к. `ShapeProvider` работает в зависимости от состояний, то фигура возвращается через метод `IShapeProviderState - GetShape(ShapeProvider provider, ref shapesLeft)`, который вызывает `Provider.CreateShape()`. Не хочу, чтобы `CreateShape` можно было вызывать извне.

```
interface IShapeProvider {
    Shape GetShape();
}

interface IShapeProviderState {
    Shape GetShape(ShapeProvider provider);
}
class Square : Shape {

}
class Rect : Shape {

}
class SquareProvider : IShapeProvider {
    public Shape GetShape() {
        return new Square();
    }
}
class ShapeProviderShapesLeft : IShapeProviderState {
    public Shape GetShape(ShapeProvider provider) {
        provider.RemoveShape();
        return provider.CreateShape();
    }
}
class ShapeProviderShapesEnd : IShapeProviderState {
    public Shape GetShape(ShapeProvider provider) {
        throw new Exception("Figures ended");
    }
}

class ShapeProvider {
    int shapesLeft = 10;    
    public IShapeProviderState State;
    public IShapeProvider Provider {get;set;} //по клику ставим какой-либо провайдер
    public ShapeProvider() : this(null) {

    }
    public ShapeProvider(IShapeProvider provider) {
        Provider = provider;
    }
    public Shape GetShape() {
        return State.GetShape(this);
    }
    public Shape CreateShape() {
        if(Provider != null)
            return Provider.GetShape();
        else 
            throw new Exeption("ShapeProvider wasn't set");
    }
    public Shape CreateShape(IShapeProvider provider) {
        if(provider != null) {
            return provider.GetShape();
        } else {
            throw new Exeption("ShapeProvider wasn't set");           
        }
    }
    private int ShapesLeft {
        get {
            return shapesLeft;
        }
        set {
            shapesLeft = value;
            AmountHasChanged();
        }
    }
    public void RemoveShape() {
        --ShapesLeft; //вызываем set
    }
    public void AddShape() {
        ++ShapesLeft; //вызываем set
    }
    private void AmountHasChanged() {
        if(shapesLeft == 0)  {
            State = new ShapeProviderShapesEnd();
        }else if(shapesLeft > 0) {
            State = new ShapeProviderShapesLeft();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите на реализацию баз данных в C#. System.Data.Common и там System.Data.SqlClient

Comment: Если провйдер  IShapeProvider - интерфейс  - никак, если  IShapeProvider класс - то можно CreateShape поставить в protected (тогда оно будет доступно условно разработчикам) или в private.

Comment: Условие доступа к protected - ваш класс (который хочет доступится к методу) должен обязательно наследовать тот в котором член/метод обьявлен в protected. Всем другим доступ закрыт (кроме лазейки Reflection). Если private не выйдет - ставьте protected